# Runtime for Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, sieve

I am currently working on making a sieve for school. Here is my code so far:

```
public static List<Integer> sieve(int input) {
    int[] numbers = new int[input - 2 + 1];
    int prime = 2; 
    // start of with 2 since first prime w/ specific multiples
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = prime; i <= input; i++) {
      numbers[counter] = i;
      counter++;
    }

    // Main sieve logic: remove all multiples of that number (except itself), move onto next number in ArrayList (which must be prime)

  for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
    for (int j = findIndex(numbers, prime) + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
      if (numbers[j] % prime == 0) {
        numbers[j] = 0;
      } 
    }


    for (int k = findIndex(numbers, prime) + 1; k < numbers.length; k++) {
      if (numbers[k] != 0) {
        prime = numbers[k];
        break;
      }
    }

  }



    pushZerosToEnd(numbers, numbers.length);

    List<Integer> cleanerResult = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int y = 0; y < numbers.length; y++) {
      if (numbers[y] != 0) {
        cleanerResult.add(numbers[y]);
      }
    }

    return cleanerResult;
  }

// Assume that pushZerosToEnd() and findIndex() do their specified action
```

Because this involves many loops, I know that this method will not be efficient or have high runtimes for bigger inputs. However, how would I find the average runtime (in Big O) of my current code so far?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithmic_complexity

Comment: Maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210081/checking-run-time-in-intellij-idea If you use Intellij you can install the VisualVM plugin to check for the runtimes or you can use the other methods that are outlined in the post above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)