# How to "time" a Java Program in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am currently using [time](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command from the terminal to check how much time my java program took, using the following command.

```
time java  -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=40 TestingNumberOfThreads

// Result
real    0m4.356s
user    0m46.273s
sys 0m0.702s
```

Is there a way I can achieve the same from IntelliJ?

Comment: I mean, why cant you use , System.currentTimeMillis() at the beginning and at the end of the program . Simply subtract these values to get execution time

Comment: Honestly, you do not **time** java applications. If you perceive a performance problem, you **benchmark** them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java ...

Comment: @NiksVij I can definitely do that and I use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get more accurate results whenever required, I just want to know if there is a way to specify time command in IntelliJ. Nothing less nothing more.

Comment: @GhostCat I just want to know if there is a way to add the "time"  command from IntelliJ configurations. I don't want to debug any performance problem as of now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking Run time in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210081/checking-run-time-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 0):

You’d need a profiler. I believe the plugin VisualVM Profiler for IntelliJ might be what you’re looking for. 
Here’s the link to it: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3749-visualvm-profiler/

Answer (score 0):

To open the terminal window in Intellij,

From the main menu, select **View** | **Tool Windows** | **Terminal** or press `Alt+F12`.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html#open-terminal

Once you opened the terminal window in the IDE, you can run any command you like, including, but not limited to

```
time java  -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=40 TestingNumberOfThreads
```

You can even separate this terminal command into its own file, named to something like **mycommand.sh**. And, assuming that this file contains the command above, you can simplify your command to

```
sh <yourpath>/mycommand.sh
```