# Checking Run time in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, profiler

Can I use InteliJ Ultimate's profiler to see how long it takes for a method to be executed?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210081/checking-run-time-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two particularly helpful tools for examining the program at runtime are the debugger and profilers.

The debugger is very precise and gives you full and granular control over the execution of the program, which allows you to reproduce intricate failure conditions.

The profiler, on the other hand, offers a bird’s eye view of arbitrarily large execution chunks. It does not interfere with the running program, nor does it provide granular data as the debugger does. However, it can collect valuable information.

[Java Flight Recorder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/custom-profiler-configurations.html#jfr) – a standard profiling tool shipped as part of the JDK.

[Async Profiler](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/async-profiler.html?source=google&medium=cpc&campaign=9731172411&gclid=CjwKCAjwq9mLBhB2EiwAuYdMtQyvJVtigGiINundhy-YrBNueDfzEAlKyJfu6ZhBcxwltedd8CFV7hoCM_cQAvD_BwE) - a very accurate profiler that can also collect native call and memory allocation data.

You can read more details on [Jetbrains profiling tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cpu-profiler.html)

There are plugins as well for Intellij to do profiling, check on `File -> Settings -> Plugins` and search for Java profiler. For instance check [`JProfiler`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/253-jprofiler/).

Of course, you can use tools for benchmark calculation as [Apache Commons StopWatch](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/StopWatch.html), which provides a convenient API for timings.

```
StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
watch.start();
...
watch.stop();
System.out.println(watch.getTime());
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me about this.

However, I tried VisualVM, but I could not get the execution time of the method.

I can't change the code directly, so I can't use the StopWatch method either.

Is there any way to solve this problem using only IntelliJ?

Comment: No worries, so as I said at the answer a JetBrains Plugin could help. For instance, check the [`JProfiler`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/253-jprofiler/), with this you can see execution time in `ms`

Comment: By the way, did you check the other options I proposed, `Java Flight Recorder` and `Async Profiler`?

Comment: I tried JFR and AsyncProfiler, but they didn't get the information I wanted, and Jprofiler seems to be living up to my expectations! Does this mean that I need to install Jprofiler separately from the IntelliJ plugin?

Comment: I had 10 days free, so I tried Jprofiler, and it got the info I wanted!
Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @EinNarr that's cool :) If the answer helped you, consider accepting it so others can benefit from it too :) Have a nice day

Comment: So basically there is no built-in way in IntelliJ's profilers to see the amount of time? only percentage?